# Dynamic SQL JOIN instead of UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the below query (small snippet of the actual code) where I am doing a `UNION ALL SELECT` multiple times due to the potential for an order to have anywhere from 1 to 5 loans associated with it. However, instead of using a `UNION ALL` and adjusting only the `LoanOrder` three separate times, I was wondering how I could possibly go about (if possible) dynamically bringing in the `LoanOrder`? This way I'm not running two additional `SELECT` statements if there is actually only one Loan associated to the order. While my current method works, I'm simply trying to better optimize and learn something new for my future endeavors. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- 1st Loan Premiums
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Loan L
        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
        AND L.LoanOrder = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- 2nd Loan Premiums
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Loan L
        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
        AND L.LoanOrder = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- 3rd Loan Premiums
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Loan L
        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
        AND L.LoanOrder = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- 4th Loan Premiums
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Loan L
        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
        AND L.LoanOrder = 4
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    -- 5th Loan Premiums
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
    Orders O
    LEFT JOIN Loan L
        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
        AND L.LoanOrder = 5
```

Comment: It seems like the only thing that changes is the L.LoadOrder = #; maybe I don't understand the question properly but couldn't you just write:

`SELECT DISTINCT LoanOrder, 'Loan Premium', 'Policies' FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN Loan L ON(O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID AND L.LoanOrder IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

That will get you all Orders and IF they have a matching record on the Loan table where Loan Order is between 1 and 5, inclusive.

Comment: Also, if you only want where the Order has a Loan, add the following WHERE clause:
`WHERE L.OrdersID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Wow, I hadn't even though about using the `IN` operator. That does precisely what I need to do and eliminates the need for multiple `UNION` statements. Thank you for this! I'll go back to feeling like a fool now. :) @Kalmino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not seem to be using the `Orders` table at all.  So, I think a simpler version of your query is:

```
SELECT L.LoanOrder, 'Loan Premium' AS 'Type', 'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM Loan L
WHERE L.LoanOrder IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You may be using `orders` for filtering, but that seems unlikely.

I also removed the `distinct` -- on the grounds that it is probably unnecessary.  If a `LoanOrder` can appear on more than one row of `Loan`, then you may need it.

EDIT:

If you do need `Orders`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.LoanOrder, 'Loan Premium' AS 'Type', 'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     Loan L
     ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID AND
        L.LoanOrder IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: In the full query I am actually using the `Orders` table, I just offered a small snippet of the query. Regardless, the `IN` operator does precisely what I need to accomplish. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    L.LoanOrder
    ,'Loan Premium' AS 'Type'
    ,'Policies:' AS 'Type1'
FROM
  Orders O
  LEFT JOIN Loan 
    ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
      AND L.LoanOrder > 0
      AND L.LoanOrder < 6
```

?